# Is it okay to vote to close an answerable question as 'not enough detail'?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I answered the following question:

[Why does my published application look fine in every browser except IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20653944/117215)

After answering, I can see a number of close votes (mostly in the 'unclear what you're asking' section).  Admittedly, the question was not very detailed, but with the benefit of some experience in this area, it was sufficient for two of us to suggest what the answer would be, which has helped the OP.

So - is it ok to vote to close a question just because there is not enough detail for *you* to answer it?  As a side query, is it ok to close a question that has constructive answers on it (as long as that question is on-topic for the site)?

Comment: There isn't a "not enough detail" close reason.

Comment: I voted to re-open, but only after carefully re-reading the question. My initial reaction was that of all the close-voters, that this question simply does not describe the problem well enough to do anything but guess at the answer. But reading carefully, I missed the first go-around that he said he tested under IE and it only caused a problem under IIS. I think the problem with this question is simply that it is worded poorly and doesn't focus enough on the problem, so most people are not going to see it for what it is.

Comment: (Even so, I think it's definitely not a great question, just passable. It really *should* include more detail, even though it is answerable as it is.)

Comment: As to your actual question: If an answer does not provide enough detail to do anything but wildly guess, then it should be closed even if someone happened to guess right. In this case, I think there is evidence that it is answerable without a wild guess.

Comment: @BenLee - I agree, it's not the best question in the world, but I think there was a lot of knee jerk closing without really parsing the question in hand.

Answer (score 3):

> Admittedly, the question was not very detailed...

That's a reason to close it as "unclear what you're asking" or "describe specific problem with valid code".

> ...it was sufficient for two of us to suggest what the answer would be...

Just because you could guess the answer based on experience, doesn't make the question better. We could answer most questions we close, but we don't do this because it would be pure guess work, shooting in the dark or would require a significant amount of time to finally get to the bottom of the problem.

It's okay if you happen to guess the correct answer.

> So - is it ok to vote to close a question just because there is not enough detail for you to answer it?

Sure, if you feel there's a problem with the question, feel free to downvote, vote-to-close, comment and edit as you see fit.

> As a side query, is it ok to close a question that has constructive answers on it (as long as that question is on-topic for the site)?

As I said, having answers doesn't make the question better or even valid.

Comment: I think there is an argument however, that it is hard for junior/inexperienced developers to phrase a question using the right terminology/detail, if they are not familiar with it.  It's very easy after some years experience to forget how little you know at the start. In this case, it wasn't really a guess, given the description, you could be almost certain of the answer given.

Comment: And as for 'having answers doesn't make the question better' - surely the point of the site is to provide answers... This particular problem is one I have seen a number of people encounter over the last few years.  If a user can get a valid answer to a somewhat hard to describe problem, is that not sufficient?

Comment: First, closing is not the end of the line. Second, sure answering questions is the goal, sure it's cool if the user gets an answer, but that doesn't make the question more valid or better. Allowing bad questions will lead to more bad questions until the moment you have a horde of users going "but you allowed that other question, why not mine!?" on you. The goal of Stack Exchange is to provide answers, yes, *in a high quality*. A good answer is okay, a good answer to a good question is a win.

Comment: In this particular case, what more detail can he add?  It's an intranet site, so it's not like he can post a link for us to look at.

Comment: Version numbers of the software used, screenshots, involved OSs, if there are any oddities or special cases which we should be aware of...what OP tried before asking, what was already checked, the simplest test case with which it is reproducible...

Comment: I do see what you are saying, and will probably leave it here, as it was just a curious query, but in this case, what you have is a 'I don't know where to start looking into this' question.  I'm not sure what the details you have listed would have added to the 'answerability' of the question, and he had described a set of steps taken prior to seeing his error.  He described how it had been developed and tested and then the output of a problem once deployed.  And then he's stuck.  Screenshots would only arguably have been effective.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there are two things about that.

First is, users got courage seeing *unclear what you are asking* or *off-topic - describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it* type questions got answers and quit asking *good* questions. Since poor quality questions got answers and solutions people do not want to waste time on details.

Second is, you are guessing the answer most of the time. Or give *try if it works* type answers. These are not good since your answer may not help or helped but *do not help future visitors of that question*. Do not forget, all questions and answers in here are also future reference for other users in the community. Questions asked after this one may got closed as *duplicate* and original question is not true or accurate since the question itself is not clear.

Closed questions means there is something wrong about the question. It is either do not fit in here or it fits before but it is not welcome now.

So closing it is the best choice IMO.